# pip freeze omits certain packages

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt4, pip

At the moment, I have python-qt4 (binary packages) installed on my Ubuntu 12.10 through Ubuntu's repository. If I run `aptitude show python-qt4`, the result would be:

```
Package: python-qt4
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
...
```

However if I run `pip freeze`, I can't find PyQt nor PyQt4 entry from the output. Does pip omit certain packages from its `freeze` command? What is the cause of the problem?

Comment: Are you using virtualenv? if the installed apps are within the context of a virtual env, it would not show when you are outside the context of the virtualenv

Comment: Yes, I'm using virtualenv. But still the PyQt entry did not show up even when I didn't activate virtualenv.

Comment: well. if you had activated virtual env at the time of installing PyQt, you wont see it when you are not in virtualenv

Comment: Sorry, I didn't install PyQt using pip but using Ubuntu's repository (sudo apt-get install python-qt4). I have updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `python-qt4` package doesn't have a `.egg-info` metadata file so it's impossible for `pip` to know that it is installed.